# access zend framework session from different actions and another PHP pages

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, web-deployment

I have this code in two pages, the first one inside controller/action and the another one in normal php page in the same website:

```
     $defaultNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');


if ( isset($defaultNamespace->name) || $row1['email'] )
{
        if( !isset($defaultNamespace->name) ){          
         $defaultNamespace->name = $username;

    }
echo "Welcome back ".  $defaultNamespace->name ." <br>"; }
```

Here is my problem: 
when I open the first page it keeps a name inside  $defaultNamespace->name. and it defines another namespace for the second page though both pages are in the same website. and I have the same namespace "Default",, so I've got two names. one for each page.

do you know how can I use the same namespace inside the whole website( because here I save the session for username which means the username is logged in)

plenty of thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start `Zend_Session` **before** creating a `namespace` for the `username` :

```
Zend_Session::start();
```

But for that purpose I'll suggest you to use [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html). You can check the credential of a user and then get the username :

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
if($identity){
  echo "Welcome back ".  $identity->name." <br>";
}
```

Comment: how can I set Identity?

Comment: When you authenticate the user (in the login action). Please see the link provided in my answer.